# Always get the correct directory

Tags: html, relative-path

I know this is a noob question, but I haven't really encountered this yet or have dealt with it using .NET's `RelativeUrl()`. I just modified the directory structure of some flat HTML files and everything is broken. Of course I know why and how to fix it, but I was wondering if there was a failsafe, non-backend solution to always getting the correct path for your assets (img, script, css, etc)

Right now I know I'm going to have to do "../../[directory]/[file]" but I was hoping there was something easier that I just haven't come across.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across root-relative paths? Basically they're paths that are, obviously I suppose, relative to the root of the website, of the form:

```
/directoryName/fileName.html
```

Further information: http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php

Comment: yeah i tried that, no dice. what is currently working is `../../etc` i guess i'm looking for a character i didn't know about, like `~` in .net

Comment: @Jason, you're absolutely sure that you got the root-relative path right?

Comment: so the structure of my project is `C:/[7 directories]/[site dir]/[section dir]/file.extension`. I can't just say `/something` because that will send it back to `C:/`, right?

Comment: i'm just wondering if there's a character that will traverse backwards automatically until it finds the correct directory. i don't know that something like this exists, i was just checking

Comment: @Jason, nah, I'm afraid that automagic directory parsing is somewhat beyond the scope of...well, anything I've currently worked with, I'm sorry to say. It would make many lives much easier.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply go from the root folder everytime by putting a "/" before your path

e.g.

```
<img src='/images/image.jpg' />
```

Comment: yeah, not working. these are flat files in a much larger, deeper directory where the "root" directory is like 10 levels deep

Comment: i guess a good question would be, how can i artificially designate a folder as "root"?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible because you couldn't open up those in a browser, which is why they are 10 levels deep. All files visited in the browser are relative to root, ../is basically the only way to access those other files that I know of

Comment: Yeah I know its a pain in the ass but you can also use it to secure code by putting files at the same level as the root and including them with ../ :) you win some you loose some

Comment: haha yeah i suppose. this is for a comp for a client, but they have like 2930283620 pages, so putting them all at the same level is probably more of a pain as finding what i'm trying to work on becomes impossible as complexity increases. oh well. thanks anyways.